# How to recursively change permissions with backup file comparing permissions

Tags: linux, terminal, backup

So in my work i did a mistake and it change all the file permissions (file owner and group) recursively inside a folder. I have the backup of that folder. I'm working inside a nsf server and my idea is to copy the permissions of the backup directory to the directory where i did the mistake recursively. All the folders and files have the same name and i want to grab the permissions from each file/directory from the backup and copy the permissions to the original directory, recursively.

Comment: That will depend on what that backup looks like ... tarballs? Simple rsync? Dedicated proprietary software?

Comment: I have the files but for some business decisions i cant just replace the folder for the backup so i was thinking like clone each permission of the backup folder to the directory that i did the mistake. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I understand that - but in which form are you able to extract the ownerships & permissions from the backup? Which is where my comment/question above comes in.

Comment: i'm thinking about a bash script or something inside the linux terminal

Comment: *sigh* .... and what data is that supposed to operate on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chown can be uded to change ownership of a file or firectort

`chown -R root:user /dir`

changes the file ownership to user

-R perform the command recursively in a directory

same for

`chmod -R 600 /dir`

then you specify your permission and ownership in your own format